# Firebase, TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-hosting

Whenever I try to deploy files to Firebase Hosting, I keep get the following error:

```
 [2018-11-01T09:36:18.073Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY undefined
 [2018-11-01T09:36:18.075Z] TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
     at module.exports (C:\Users\dilzy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\responseToError.js:10:13)
     at Request._callback (C:\Users\dilzy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\api.js:47:25)
     at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\dilzy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
     at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dilzy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\request\request.js:1157:10)
     at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dilzy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\request\request.js:1079:12)
     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Not sure why it's happening and normally deploy works fine expect till now.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code of what you try to deploy. Preferably all the files...

Comment: @RenaudTarnec All the files? There happens to be quite a bit. The issue on my end or Firebases, because I've tried this before and it worked fine

Comment: Do you deploy only hosting files? Or also some Cloud Functions?

Comment: Also what happens if you logout and login again (with the CLI commands, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#administrative_commands)

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version of `firebase-tools` by running `npm install -g firebase-tools`.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec no, just hosting

Comment: @Grimthorr I’ll try that to see if I’m using an older version

Comment: @RenaudTarnec oh thanks, I’ll try that too

Comment: I'm stuck with exactly the same problem. Did anything work for you? EDIT: Updating `firebase-tools` again did it for me.

Comment: @EluciusFTW I reinstalled Node.js and npm to the latest version, tried it again and everything worked fine. Hope it works for you too

Answer (score 4):

Updating `firebase-tools` fixed it for me: `npm install -g firebase-tools`

Answer (score 0):

PSA: firebase-tools v11.3.0 will throw a similar error:

`FirebaseError: Failed to make request: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')`.

To fix it, install an earlier version of Firebase tools:
`npm install -g firebase-tools@11.18.0`

GitHub bug report: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5334